# Update module version inside parent

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I have a maven parent project with 2 jar module, 2 war module and 1 ear module. Each war module have both jar modules dependency and I tried with `versions-maven-plugin` to have always the latest version .

This work without a problem and I have my war's pom updated with the latest version of the dependency, so: there is a way to do the same thing but running a build from the parent ? 
Because I tried to build the parent with the same goal but it doesn't work.

Here the goal:

```
versions:use-latest-releases clean install
```

Here the plugin's implementation:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>groupId:artifactId</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I dont really understand what do you want to be doing. Do you have a main parent project with reactor that first builds jars, then wars and then ears and you want them to always have the same versions?

Comment: Usually you build all modules with the same version, which is the project version. You can use this as well to define inter-module dependencies.

Comment: My jar modules are ws so they will grow differently than the war modules, they will grow faster. I'm trying to update automactly the version of the jar modules inside my war modules when i do "clean install" from parent project. Now I musto do it with a Maven Build on the single war module, but seen that they could be more than the actual two I want a better solution than "build" every single module every time